# Using natural numbers $1,2,...n,$ in how many ways can the number $n$ be formed from the sum of **one** or more smaller natural numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions, natural-numbers

> Using natural numbers $1,2,...n,$ in how many ways can the number $n$ be formed from the sum of **one** or more smaller natural numbers?

I thought it would be an easy problem but i couldn't figure it out. Example: For n = 4, we have **4**$,1 + 3, 2 + 2, 1 + 1 + 2,$**1 + 1 + 1 + 1** for a total of $5.$

Comment: What prevents you from writing $4=1+1+1+1$?

Comment: Thanks, i corrected that. I guess i can also add 4 if i changed the question to 1 or more sums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is complicated and you've missed $4=1+1+1+1$ in your question. You are looking for [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) - the link has a good bibliography. The exact formula is surprisingly complicated. Your question involves subtracting 1 from the number of partitions as conventionally calculated.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes that is what I wanted to do. Indeed it seems complicated than i thought.

Comment: The problem gets a lot easier if one treats different orders of the same numbers as different (e.g. $1+3$ being different from $3+1$)... but that's a completely different beast to tackle :-)

Comment: Luckily for my problem permutations don't matter.